# Set vertex color attribute by vertex coreness

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to make a decomposed coreness plot similar to this:
[image: core shells]

I could just pass `coreness` to the `vertex.color` parameter in an igraph plot and it will assign colours automatically, but I'd rather plot with DiagrammeR. It can use an igraph object, I just need to assign all the attributes needed first, in this case the coreness and a corresponding colour for each vertex. My question is, how can I assign a colour attribute to vertices based on their coreness?

EDIT: I've got as far as creating a palette for the core shells, I'm just a bit lost as to how to assign them as an attribute, though it looks like it should be straight-forward.

Example code:

```
library(viridis)
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_literal(1-2, 1-3, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 3-4, 4-5, 1-4, 2-6, 6-7)
V(g)$core <- coreness(g, "all")
col_df <- data.frame(node = V(g)$name, core = V(g)$core)
fillcol <- data.frame(core = 1:3, col = plasma(3))
col_df <- merge(col_df, fillcol)

  core node       col
1    1    6 #0D0887FF
2    1    7 #0D0887FF
3    2    5 #CC4678FF
4    3    1 #F0F921FF
5    3    2 #F0F921FF
6    3    3 #F0F921FF
7    3    4 #F0F921FF
```